# submiting data from a dynamic table to database - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a html webpage which has a table that gets data from a table in my database. Each row has a button that when clicked gets added into another table on the webpage dynamically using javascript. The dynamic table has a submit button which when clicked, the data in the table should get added into a table in my database. What my problem is that the contents in the table do not get added to the database but each time I press the submit button a new row with a unique id gets added. Also theres a input text box which also gets added correctly to my database. This makes me believe that my database connection is working but for some reason the data in the table does not get added. How can I make the data in the dynamic table get submited into the database? Here is my code. Code has been updated with suggestions.

```
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM inventoryCars";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
?>                              
<div class="inventory">
    <div class ="cars">
    <table>
        <?php           
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                $RegNo = $row["regNo"];
                $CarMake = $row["carMake"];
                $CarModel = $row["carModel"];
        ?>  
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="regNo" value="<?php echo $row['regNo'] ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="carMake" value="<?php echo $row['carMake'] ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="carModel" value="<?php echo $row['carModel'] ?>">
            <td><?php echo $row["regNo"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["carMake"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["carModel"] ?></td>
            <td><button onclick="addRowToTable('<?php echo $RegNo ?>','<?php echo $CarMake ?>','<?php echo $CarModel ?>')">+</button></td>
        </tr>
        <script type ="text/javascript">
            function addRowToTable(regNo, carMake, carModel) {
                var table = document.getElementById("newhireTBL");
                var row = table.insertRow(0);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                cell1.innerHTML = regNo;
                cell2.innerHTML = carMake;
                cell3.innterHTML = carModel;
                }
        </script>
        <?php
            }
            } 
        ?>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>              

    <div class="order">
    <div class ="newhire">
    <table id="newhireTBL">
    </table>

    <form action = "addNewHire.php" method = "post">
            <input type="hidden" name="regNo" value="<?php echo $row['regNo'] ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="carMake" value="<?php echo $row['carMake'] ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="carModel" value="<?php echo $row['carModel'] ?>">

            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

addNewHire.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php require_once("connectToSQL.php"); ?>
<?php
echo "<pre>";var_dump($_POST);echo "</pre>";die;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $RegNo = $_POST['regNo'];
    $CarMake = $_POST['carMake'];
    $CarModel = $_POST['carModel'];

    $_SESSION["regNo"] = $RegNo;
    $_SESSION["carMake"] = $CarMake;
    $_SESSION["carModel"] = $CarModel;

$sql = "INSERT INTO newHire(regNo, carMake, carModel)
        VALUES('$RegNo', '$CarMake', '$CarModel')";

if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
header("location:order_success.php");
echo "Order has been made";
} else {
header("location:order_fail");
echo "Order fail";

}
}
?>

}
?>
```

testing shows this

```
array(4) { 
["regNo"]=>
string(0) "" 
["carMake"]=> 
string(0) "" 
["carModel"]=>
string(0) "" 
["submit"]=> 
string(6) "Submit" 
}
```

Comment: Before your `if-condition`, in the file `addNewHire.php`, add `echo "<pre>";var_dump($_POST);echo "</pre>";die;` and check the output. With `var_dump` you get the content displayed and with `pre`-tag the output is formatted in a more readable way. With `die` you simply stop the programme.

Comment: Hi @AMartinNo1 this is the output, am I right in thinking that nothing is being added to the variables?  `array(4) {
  ["regNo"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["carMake"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["carModel"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["submit"]=>
  string(6) "Submit"
}`

Comment: @ShowmanPusha Well, the array keys exists. As of that content should have been transmitted as well. Try what Mark suggested.

Comment: @AMartinNo1 do you have any other suggestions? I have tried whats been suggested but I'm having no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form and table tag have an invalid nesting, and this may prevent the form data being submitted. Try moving end tag for the "newhireTBL" table immediately below the table's starting tag (outside the form), so the table and form tags don't overlap.

Eg:

```
<table...>
</table>

<form...>
</form>
```

EDIT: here's a basic example with some dummy data that may help you solve your problem. Good luck!

```
 <?php
    $rows = array(
        array(
            "regNo" => "abc123",
            "carMake" => "toyota",
            "carModel" => "camry",
        ),
        array(
            "regNo" => "def456",
            "carMake" => "ford",
            "carModel" => "laser",
        ),        
    );
?>    

<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
    <?php echo $row["regNo"] ?>
    <?php echo $row["carMake"] ?>
    <?php echo $row["carModel"] ?>
    <button onclick="addRow('<?php echo $row["regNo"] ?>','<?php echo $row["carMake"] ?>','<?php echo $row["carModel"] ?>')">+</button>
    <br/>
<?php endforeach ?>

<form action = "addNewHire.php" method = "post">
    <input id=regNo type="text" name="regNo" value="">
    <input id=carMake type="text" name="carMake" value="">
    <input id=carModel type="text" name="carModel" value="">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type ="text/javascript">
    function addRow(regNo, carMake, carModel) {
        document.getElementById('regNo').value = regNo;
        document.getElementById('carMake').value = carMake;
        document.getElementById('carModel').value = carModel;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Im guessing you mean the `<table id="newhireTBL">` and `</table>`, this stops the dynamic table from working and when I click submit I get the same output as above.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the reference to the table in the script. Answer edited to suggest modifying the table & form nesting, instead of removing the table.

Comment: Same as above unfortunately, nothing seems to be going into the arrays.

Comment: Looks like the use of the $row variable in the form is out of scope of the while loop, so the hidden inputs are blank. Verify this is the problem by setting one of the hidden fields to an explicit value, eg, value="xxx". You could fix by setting the input fields inside the form from the addRowToTable function.

Comment: I set the regNo to "xxx" which outputted `["regNo"]=>
  string(3) "xxx"` this shows your diagnosis works. So in the script I should put `$RegNo = $row["regNo"];
                $CarMake = $row["carMake"];
                $CarModel = $row["carModel"];`

Comment: or should I do it by giving the hidden inputs id's e.g the hidden regNo has a id called "regnoID" so in the function i add `document.getElementById("regnoID").value = <?php $RegNo ?>;`?

Comment: Use document.getElementById("regnoID").value = regNo; PHP was used to create each function call before sending the page to the browser, so the parameter values (regNo, etc) are already defined by the time you click the + button. The values are passed in to the function. You don't want to use php inside the javascript function. Also, you only want a single function, so move the script block (including start and end tag) outside of while... loop.

Comment: Thank you, I have now managed to get it to submit values, however, It only submits the values of the last clicked button. Is there a way to get it to submit all of the values in a button?

Comment: If you still are looking for an answer: You can use an array for each input field. `<input name="regNo[]"/>` Then you can iterate through each input field. E.g. every input which name start with "regNo". In each iteration you can access the other inputs like "carModel" using the current `index`. With php it is easier.

Comment: @Mark, I just want to know, How you got $rows array data? I know that is static as of now but what code we have to use here to get the data?

Comment: @NarenVerma $rows are commonly obtained from a database query, for example [fetch_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

Comment: OH! right. User fetching the data. I though the user inserting the dynamic data. Any idea how can we get dynamic data on the process page?